# Multiple threads processing same record of ResultSet

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, resultset

I have to process almost 40k records and pass them to my webservice to push data.Without using Multithreading it is working fine but is taking too much of time which is not acceptable. I am trying to apply multithreading here but the issue is that i can see in the logger that multiple threads are processing same record of resultset(even though i am passing it after doing resultset.next)

I am new to Java Multithreading any help will be appreciated.

This is the thread creation and job assingning  part.

```
 ExecutorService exservice =Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);


       while(rs.next()){

        exservice.execute(new EmployeeThread(rs,userservice,logger));

         }

    exservice.shutdown();
```

Comment: ResultSets are not threadsafe (the data structure holds one item at a time).  Why is the serial solution not fast enough?

Comment: Inside each thread we are calling webservices where we are passing the values from resultset one at a time and we have applied certain validations also which is getting checked for each record.So i think thats why it is taking time. Can i use Listof Hashmap instead of ResultSet and pass it to the Thread as argument , will it be thread safe then??

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a profiler to understand where time is spent.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen JDBC requires that result sets are thread safe, it is just that without external synchronization, the operations on a result set might not make sense and be one big race condition (eg one thread trying to process a row, while another thread calls `rs.next()`, so the first thread sees parts of the original and the next row).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Thanks for the detailed explaination. So you are saying with each while loop iteration when rs.next() is getting executed it reflects in all th thread as we are sharing the same object of ResultSet so all threads might start seeing the same data.Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: Yes, you will need to extract the data in a single thread, and then push the extracted data to the worker-threads .Also, consider carefully if using multiple threads will actually speed up processing, in a lot of cases, single-threaded processing is simpler, and using multiple threads will not always speed things up.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am aware that the ResultSet alters atomically and in that sense is thread safe, but the problem is not that, but that a single ResultSet cannot be used simultaneously in multiple threads like OP would like to due to its design.

Comment: @ManishKumar I still strongly recommend that you get actual numbers on where the time is spent.  You might be able to optimize in a different way than you expect, when you know.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen,@Mark Rotteveel Instead of using ResultSet i have copy pasted the resultset data to ListOfHashMap and then passed each object to the Task assigned.Now it is taliking less time but is there any other way of doing it. Please let me know.

Comment: Where did the profiler tell you the time was spent?

Answer (score 2):

you are calling `rs.next` outside the worker threads, so they all process the same record. additionally, you are iterating on the result set outside the worker threads, so they all process just one record? .

here's what you should do:

1. execute the select statement into a `RowSet` . unlike `ResultSet`, `RowSet` can be disconnected from the SQL connection, allowing you freedom to iterate over the set several times. `RowSet` is also serializeable, allowing it to be passed over networks.
2. for each woring thread, you determine its working 'shard': if you have 1000 records to process and 3 working threads, than thread #1 will process records 0-333, thread #2 will process records 334-666 and so on.
3. Pass the `RowSet` to the working threads with respective shard (start and end indices). each thread will iterate and skip until start index, and process the records of its shard.

To get you started, Here is the official tutorial on `RowSet` from Oracle documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and please correct me if my understanding is wrong. We have three fixed threads and 40k jobs (number of records in the resultset). Each job is getting created when while loop runs and when loop runs resultSet start pointing to next record and in the thread i am using resultSet.get() to retrieve data.Each thread is processing a separate job as it uses blocking queue. So how come same threads are using same record.

Comment: it's because `ResultSet` doesn't work like how you imagine it. it doesn't wotk like an iterator. imagine the set as an `ArrayList`. so you are iterating over it using an `Iterator` , but you pass the `List` itself to the working threads (not `Iterator.next()`)

Comment: every job will process the row that was fetched by the last executing `rs.next()`, not the row that was fetched when the job was created

Comment: what you *can* do, is after calling `rs.next()`, pass the contents of the set to a custom Java Bean and pass that POJO to the worker thread

Comment: i get the POJO passing idea but i am not getting how common the working threads are pointing to the previous resultset record.

Comment: I'm not sure using row set makes a lot of sense here. It has much of the same downsides as a result set. Creating POJOs and publishing to POJOs to the worker threads might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next()) {
 var1= rs.getblob(); 
 var2 = rs.getstring(); 
 es.execute(() ->{ 
     print var1; 
     print var2; 
     calllogic();
 }); 
}
 rs.close(); 
 st.close(); 
 es.shutdown();
```